# How to get partial view to be unloaded when a cancel button within it is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I'm using .NET MVC3.... and I have a partial view that renders into a page when a button is clicked...

```
$('#myLink').click(function () {
     $('#partial2Div').load(this.href);
     return false;
});
```

But... I have a cancel button INSIDE this partial view when it loads and I'm trying to figure out how to have the 'original' page preserve its state (it has edit fields on it) when this cancel button is pressed... and just have the partial view disappear.

Comment: What do you mean, *preserve its state*?  You're only touching **partial2Div**, so why would the rest of the page change?

Comment: Is `#partialDiv2` being replaced with new content in your example? (I.e. you want the content previous to the `.load()` call to come back?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have updated the `partial2Div` then well change your logic to not do so instead have another div where your partial will be inserted, if thats not the case and `partial2Div` is just meant for that partial all you got to do is hide that `div` as follows:

```
$("cancel").click(function(){
   $("partial2Div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't unload a partial view without loading the full page.

But you can show/hide it, simply put the partial view in a div and hide the div on button click. Or remove the element completely from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/), there is a callback for when the contents have been loaded. You should be able to try something like this:

```
$('#myLink').click(function () {
     $('#partial2Div').load(this.href, function(){
         $("#id-of-cancel-button").click(function(){
             $("#partial2Div").hide();
         });
     });
     return false;
});
```

Just make sure you reference the id of the cancel button when you bind it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("cancel").click(
  function()
  {    
    $("partial2Div").html(''); 
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Truth is, you cant unload it.

You can set the style of the div to 'display: none' with.

$("partial2Div").hide();